# simply scale up phone xml layout for tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

I designed my app for phone. If all I want for it on Tablet is just to scale up everything (i.e. bigger images, more distances), Is there a way to ensure this happen when doing my XML (or in the code)? Or should I create a different xml for xlarge screens?

I always come across the question and don't know the answer. Please don't refer me to the documentation of supporting multiple screens because I read it many time and it shows how you can customize for diff screen sized. In my case, I just simply everything scaled up keeping the same ration as the phone

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `RelativeLayout`s

Comment: yes it will keep the placement right but the dp values of distances and width/hight are still the same as the phone